# CSS in mail causes horizontal scroll

Tags: css, email, styles, mailer

I am developing an application with Symfony and I have a very basic confirmation email with very little CSS, but enough to cause horizontal scrolling.

This is the code of my mail (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GeoSport Authenticator</title>
</head>
<body style="box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden">
<div>

    <h1 style="margin: 5px 0; text-align: center;">
        GeoSport
    </h1>

    <div style="text-align: center; border: 2px solid lightblue; background-color: rgb(189, 221, 231); padding: 10px;
                margin: 0 auto; width: 75vw; border-radius: 10px;">

        <h2 style="margin: 15px 0;">
            ¡Bienvenido a GeoSport!
        </h2>

        <p>Por favor, confirme su correo electrónico haciendo click en el siguiente botón:</p>
        <p class="link">
            <a style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px; border: 10px solid black; background-color: black;
             text-decoration: none; border-radius: 10px; color: white;" href="{{ signedUrl|raw }}">
                Confirmar mi correo
            </a>
        </p>
        <p>Este enlace expirará en 1 hora.</p>

        <p>¡Saludos!</p>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

It can be seen perfectly from the mobile phone, but if I open the mail from the PC there is a horizontal scroll, why does this happen?

Mail from PC:
[image: Mail from PC]

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the `width: 75vw;` applied on your main `<div>`. Because webmails have their own interface, using viewport units like this is likely to cause horizontal overflow. You can either remove it or replace it with `max-width: 75vw;`.